How to keep a counter to track no-match and no-input event handler globally in the Dialogflow CX chatbot
Is it possible to keep a counter to track no-match and no-input event handler globally in the chatBot. Once the counter hit 5 anywhere in the conversation the chatbot goes to the exit page.

You can do this in a single session by incrementing a session parameter via parameter preset. But there is no way to do this across sessions without using a webhook. One possible way is to use a flexible webhook and call the Dialogflow detectIntent API with a static session ID. You can then persist the parameter in that session. Just note that the session expires 30 minutes after the last request. If that is not acceptable, you need to persist via e.g. cloud function in some storage (usually a database).
